# Switching scene from controller by calling method in Application

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm doing a project, where I have to switch scenes depending on user input. At the moment I have a Gui-Class, which is an Application and loads the first fxml-File, it is launched by a MainController-class:

```
public class MainController {


public MainController() {
    Application.launch(Gui.class);
}

}
```

The Gui-Class:

```
public class Gui extends Application{

Stage primaryStage;


//I wanna ideally use this method to switch scenes
public void switchen(String nextScene) throws Exception
{
    Parent nextS;
    if(nextScene.equals("singleMenue"))
    {
        nextS = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SingleMenue.fxml"));
        primaryStage.hide();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(nextS, 900, 600));
        primaryStage.show()
    }

}


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    Parent decisionScene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Decision.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("title");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(decisionScene, 900, 600));
    primaryStage.show();

    }
```

I also have a different Controller-class for each .fxml-file (this is the first):

```
public class DecisionController {

@FXML 
private Button singleButton;

@FXML 
private Button multiButton;

public DecisionController() {

}

@FXML
private void buttonPressed(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{

    if(event.getSource() == singleButton)
    {
        System.out.println("single");
        // I wanna somehow call switch("singleMenue"); here
    }
    else if(event.getSource() == multiButton)
    {
        System.out.println("multi");
    }

}
}
```

So how do I switch the Scenes from inside the Controller now ?

I tried to generally go with the MVC-pattern but I don't know how it should be possible for my DecisionController-Object to call a method inside the Gui-Application. I would need to reach inside a running Thread here, right ? 
I also don't know how I could turn over my Gui-Instance to my DecisionController, since the latter one is initialized from the Decision.fxml.

One other thing I tried was to switch the Scene directly from the DecisionController with:

```
@FXML
private void buttonPressed(ActionEvent event) throws IOException
{

    if(event.getSource() == singleButton)
    {
        System.out.println("single");

        Stage mainstage = (Stage) singleButton.getScene().getWindow();
        Parent singleScene = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SingleMenue.fxml"));
        mainstage.setScene(new Scene(singleScene, 900, 600));

    }
    else if(event.getSource() == multiButton)
    {
        System.out.println("multi");
    }

}
```

This understandably doesn't work either since manipulation from outside the application thread isn't possible.

I'm kind of new to JavaFX & FXML so my general idea for the structure of the program might just be totally wrong, maybe this isn't how you MVC. Any feedback is much appreciated :)

Comment: "This understandably doesn't work either since manipulation from outside the application thread isn't possible." But this is being called on the FX Application Thread. In what sense doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: @James_D It gave me an error. Being already convincend that it shouldn`t work I attributed it to my idea of "manipulation from outside the application thread". After seeing your comment I looked at the code again and realised that it gave me an error because my Controller is in a different package than my .fxml-files so I have to load it differently than in the Gui. I guess it's a reminder to really look at the error messages unbiased. And of how Threads work.
Anyways thanks a lot for the quick response and helping to solve the problem :)